# Automatic Token Retrieval from Userpass login

Tags: api, hashicorp-vault

**Goal**: Automate a process by which certificates are put into Vault once they are renewed. I want to use the userpass authentication method, and then, using the Vault API, POST them into Vault. This however required a token generated from userpass login.

**Questions**: Is there a way to automatically retrieve this token and pass it to the system as an environment variable?

Code to add .pem files into Vault:

```
curl -s -k -H"Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "X-Vault-Token :$LOGIN-TOKEN" \
-X POST -d"{\"value\":\"$CERT\"}" https://example.com/v1/secret/test/server
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers always lie in the [Docs](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/commands/login.html)!

I used the -token-only flag to output the token and then using some bash magic:

```
LOGIN-TOKEN=$(vault login -method=userpass -token-only  username=<username> password=<pswd>)
```